# Is it necessary to back up Libraries while backing up a drive for formatting?

Tags: windows-7, libraries

(Windows-7) I want to back up my C: drive before formatting it. Is it necessary to back up the Libraries also? I am not interacting with Libraries myself. Only the system does the necessary actions. I understand that the 'Libraries' is a mirror image of part of the Users folder, hence perhaps backing up of Libraries is not required.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not needed.
As you wrote, they are already included in drive C.

Comment: *"As you wrote, they are already included in drive C."* Only if you didn't move your stuff earlier. Those files might actually be on D, E, or any other drive.

Comment: Right. I assumed the default setup...

Answer (score 0):

The libraries are just a loose collection of contents found in other folders.

For example, *Documents* will show everything from your own *Documents* folder as well as the shared *Documents* of *All Users*.

Those special folders are just an amalgamation of contents found elsewhere.

Whether that content is actually included in your backup depends on the storage location. By default, your user files will be found under `C:\Users`, which might have a localized alias such as `C:\Benutzer` based on your system locale.

If you've moved any of those folders to a different drive, then it won't necessarily be included though.